# Issue deleting documents from dialogbox

Tags: xpages

When deleting a document from a dialog box extension library. I'm facing an issue "Error: Domino Document has been deleted.". I have a repeat control with an icon trash for deleting document.

Using this code on a link and I setup a full refresh onclick

```
var deleteUNID = ItemOrderRow.getUniversalID();
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(deleteUNID);
doc.remove(true);
```

Any idea how to counter the issue ?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see more code, but I'm going to guess that the issue is what you're refreshing.  I assume you're doing a partial refresh?  You should be refreshing the repeat control I'd think.  I suspect you're refreshing "ItemOrderRow"...

Comment: Doing a Full Update, I tried to do the refresh on the repeat control but no better success. I do this within a dialog box.

Comment: Showing more code might help.  You are closing the dialog box after the delete and before the refresh I assume...

Comment: the xpage is for ordering items and the dialog box is showing the cart content. I'm not closing after deleting one item.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not deleting the version of the document in memory, Try this instead:

```
ItemOrderRow.getDocument().remove(true)
```

or possibly

```
ItemOrderRow.remove(true)
```

Comment: ItemOrderRow.remove(true) is not correct.

I tried with ItemOrderRowe.getDocument().remove(true) even with a full update the repeat control in the dialog box is not getting refreshed.

Comment: ok, strange, so did ItemOrderRow.getDocument().remove(true) work?

Comment: It's deleting the document no error but not refreshing the content of the repeat control in the dialog box. other fields are getting refreshed (e.g. a sum of item order value)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of the content of my dialog box:

```
<xp:table>
<xp:tr>
<xp:td colspan="2">
<xp:label value="Item Name" id="lblItemName">
</xp:label>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
    <xp:label value="Quantity" id="lblQuantity">
    </xp:label>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
 <xp:label value="Unit price" id="lblPrice">
</xp:label>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:label value="Value" id="lblOrderValue">
</xp:label>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:label value="Client #" id="lblClientNumber"></xp:label>
</xp:td>
<xp:td colspan="2">
<xp:label value="Relation type" id="lblRelationType">
</xp:label>
</xp:td>
</xp:tr>
<xp:repeat id="rptArtOrder" rows="50" value="#{view3}" indexVar="ArtOrder" var="ItemOrderRow">
<xp:tr>
<xp:td>
    <xp:link escape="true" id="delOrder">
                                <xp:image url="/trashcan.png" id="image2">
                                </xp:image>
                                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"    submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
/*var deleteUNID = ItemOrderRow.getUniversalID();
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(deleteUNID);
doc.remove(true);*/
ItemOrderRow.getDocument().removePermanently(true)}]]></xp:this.action>
                                </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:text escape="true" id="OrCartItemName">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:ItemOrderRow.getColumnValue("CartItemName")}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:text escape="true" id="OrCartItemQuantity">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:ItemOrderRow.getColumnValue("CartItemQuantity")}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:text escape="true" id="OrCartItemPrice">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:ItemOrderRow.getColumnValue("CartItemPrice")}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:text escape="true" id="OrCartItemValue">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:ItemOrderRow.getColumnValue("$42")}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox2">
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="-- Choose a relation type --">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="type1">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="type2">
                                </xp:selectItem>
</xp:comboBox>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
</xp:td>
</xp:tr>
</xp:repeat>
</xp:table>
```